# Errors when adding materialized views of multiple columns that begin with the same statement

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I'm trying to combine materialized views of several columns from a table into one view but am getting errors when I try to add multiple views that start with the same function type.

E.g. I get no errors when I create the following materialized view:

```
create materialized view doh1mat as select 
    (left(replace(filename,'DOH_cumulative_text_filesSwimming PoolsSpas_',''),strpos(replace(filename,'DOH_cumulative_text_filesSwimming PoolsSpas_',''),'_')-1)),
    (trim(substring(coalesce(substring(content from 'Conducted By: (.*) Inspector Contact'),substring(content from 'Conducted  By: (.*) Inspector Contact')) from '\((.*)\)')))
    from doh1;
```

But when I try to add more columns like with the following sql:

```
create materialized view doh1mat as select 
    (left(replace(filename,'DOH_cumulative_text_filesSwimming PoolsSpas_',''),strpos(replace(filename,'DOH_cumulative_text_filesSwimming PoolsSpas_',''),'_')-1)),
    (left(NULLIF(regexp_replace(substring(content from 'Zip: (.*) Type:'), '\D','','g'), ''),5)),
    (trim(substring(coalesce(substring(content from 'Conducted By: (.*) Inspector Contact'),substring(content from 'Conducted  By: (.*) Inspector Contact')) from '\((.*)\)'))),
    (substring(content from 'Owner: (.*) Person')),
    (substring(content from 'Charge: (.*) Pool')),
    (trim(coalesce(replace(substring(content from 'VOLUME (.*) POOL L'),'.',''),replace(substring(content from 'VOLUME (.*) POOL  L'),'.','')))),
    (trim(coalesce(substring(content from 'Pool  Operator: (.*) Phone'),substring(substring(content from 'Pool  Operator: (.*) Phone') from '(.*) Phone')))),
    (substring(content from 'Phone: (.*) Purpose')),
    (substring(content from 'Phone: (.*) Phone')),
    (substring(content from 'Email: (.*) Pool  Operator')),
    (substring(content from 'Address\(es\): (.*) DOH'))
    from doh1;
```

I get "ERROR: column "left" specified more than once".

So I tried changing sql to put a column name in front of each function:

```
create materialized view doh1mat as select 
    (phone_operator(substring(content from 'Phone: (.*) Phone'))),
    (email_string(substring(content from 'Email: (.*) Pool  Operator'))),
    (email_string_2(substring(content from 'Address\(es\): (.*) DOH')))
    from doh1;
```

But the I get "ERROR: function phone_operator(text) does not exist".

**Is there a way to "rename" or alias the columns when creating the materialized view?**

**If not, how can I create the materialized views without Postgres mistaking the first statement for a column name?** Also, why does a statement like LEFT(... is a column name while it still performs the command?

Comment: Use a column alias in the select: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES e.g. `(substring(content from 'Phone: (.*) Purpose')) as purpose`

Comment: YES, thank you a_horse_with_no_name. I'm obviously still very new to this. I don't know why I didn't try that earlier.

Comment: I'm answering the question with your answer just to mark it but will accept and upvote your solution if you decide to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

See a_horse_with_no_name's comment for the answer.

I just needed to add an alias after each column like:

```
create materialized view doh1mat as select 
    (substring(content from 'Phone: (.*) Purpose')) as phone_facility,
    (substring(content from 'Phone: (.*) Phone')) as phone_operator,
    (substring(content from 'Email: (.*) Pool  Operator')) as email_string,
    (substring(content from 'Address\(es\): (.*) DOH')) as email_string_2
    from doh1;
```